# Refactoring Javascript code from Aspx file

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css

I am refactoring the web project,where java script and css code is written inside the .aspx file.Now I am removing java script and css code from the aspx files and maintaining that the code in respective css and js files with their reference in aspx files.

It is straight forward for me if java script code is written in one place and inside  the funtion.Here in the example code not all java script code is inside the function and some of the script are inside the div block.I am not able to put these script in separate file.Moreover I am new bee in Java script and web development please help me on this.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <script type="text/javascript">
       -------code-----------       
    </script>
    <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm())
       {%>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <div class="formColWhole" style="width: 935px;">
          <script type="text/javascript">

              document.body.style.cursor = 'default';

              document.forms[0].action = '<% = ViewData["RegisterPageUrl"].ToString() %>';

              function IndicateProcessing() {
              if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
                  if (Page_ClientValidate() == false) { return false; }
              }


              var cancelButton = document.getElementById("<% = buttonCancel.ClientID %>");
              if (cancelButton != null) {
                  cancelButton.disabled = true;
              }

              document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';

              return true;
              }
              function submitForm() {
              IndicateProcessing();
              // _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Register', 'Register submit Click', 'Register submit']);
              // avoid duplicate submission
              var button = $("#buttonSend");
              button.attr('disabled', true).html('');

              document.forms[0].submit();
                        }
          </script>
    </div>
    <div class="formColWhole" style="width: 100%;">
       --------code----

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var selectCountryText = document.getElementById("<% = selectCountry.ClientID %>").value;
        var regions = document.getElementById("region");
        regions.firstChild.text = selectCountryText;
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: you can dupe your embedded fields into a blank page and ajax/parse that, or you can live with a small amount of config being printed into the main view. anything else will likely require a bit of re-factoring.

Comment: What do you mean by "embedded fields into a blank page"

Comment: i mean you dupe your current page but strip out all the other HTML except the embeded vars, no nav, no script tags, etc. you can then fetch the embeded data from anywhere instead of having to be on a specific page...